# Why we passing values using parameters?

Tags: c#, sql-server

option 1: in this values are inserted using parameters

```
string insertstr = "INSERT INTO table_name(eid, eName, Dept) " + 
                    "VALUES(@eid, @eName, @dept)";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertstr, con);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@eid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ename", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = textBox2.Text.ToString();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@dept", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = textBox3.Text.ToString();
```

Option 2:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO table_name(eid,eName,Dept) values('"+ textBox1.Text +"','"+ textBox2.Text +"','"+ Textbox3.Text +"'", con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Most of the projects i had seen the 1st option... what is the use of passing values using parameters?? any advantages by passing values using parameters?? your suggestion plz..

Answer (score 8):

You don't have to care about quoting special characters. If you forget to quote a SQL-Injection attack is possible.

If you use Option 2 and one enters the following into `Textbox3`

```
'); DELETE * FROM table_name; --
```

the following SQL statements are excecuted:

```
INSERT INTO table_name(eid,eName,Dept) values ('value1','value2','');
DELETE * FROM table_name; -- ')
```

The second statement deletes every row from `table_name`. Instead of a delete statement any possible statement could be inserted there.

Answer (score 1):

Several reasons:

- You don't have to worry to escape special characters (like `'`) to avoid SQL errors or SQL injections (as explained by *H-Man2*).
- You don't have to worry to transform C# types to SQL types. For instance:

  - If your [`NumberDecimalSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator.aspx) is equal to the comma `,` and you want to insert a `Double` value in your database, you normally have to replace the comma by a point. No need to worry about that with parameters.
  - No need to worry about `DateTime` formats neither.
  - ...
- I find also the code more readable and easier to maintain with parameters when your SQL queries start to have a great length.

Answer (score 0):

You should **NEVER** use option 2.

This is very bad practise, and very open to SQL Injection.

Always stick with Option 1. This is the best option by far.

Read here for more information on SQL Injection:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection